# Migrating to GitHub from SVN (VisualSVN Server) keeping SVN version numbers

Tags: github, svn

Ok so we are trying to move from SVN (VisualSVN Server in house) to GitHub and we want to keep version numbers, all the posts so far I have tried to follow don't seem to find the version numbers. And I end up getting this 'Unable to determine upstream SVN information from HEAD history'

So we used the GitHub import utility to bring over the SVN repository but everything I have tried after that doesn't seem to work to allow us to access version numbering from SVN.

If anyone can help me please, I am not really great in either SVN or GitHub and all advice would be very welcome.

What do you mean by "we want to keep version numbers"? - The version info from SVN (revision numbers I think they call it) we need for historic records (we are getting rid of SVN) it would be great to see them as a message in the commit comments for historic SVN items. I may be using the wrong terms sorry.

Comment: What do you mean by "we want to keep version numbers"? Commits in Git are identified by their hash, not incremental integers.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Chris I have added some extra info to help make my question clearer I hope.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not really great in either SVN or GitHub

Hire anybody proficient in at least one theme: SVN or Git (Github is service on top of Git and it's irrelevant to task "repository migration")

Another way is:

- read and **understand** [git-svn topic](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) from Git Book
- convert SVN-repository to **local Git-repo**
- using fresh Git, discover and use [`find-rev`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#Documentation/git-svn.txt-emfind-revem) subcommand in git-svn for your task:

> When given an SVN revision number of the form rN, returns the
> corresponding Git commit hash (this can optionally be followed by a
> tree-ish to specify which branch should be searched). When given a
> tree-ish, returns the corresponding SVN revision number.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply, I appreciate that getting someone in to do this would probably be best but also I want to learn. with your solution would we always be able to see the revision number as in would it add them as some sort of comment?

Comment: @Robo - you can have it always, without additional operations from your side (at least I understood doc this way) ... maybe just not in all forks of Git-repo, produced during migration